# Access Variable outside a While loop, that is always updating

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I wrote a program that constantly updates your current CPU frequency and CPU usage using a while loop. I want to access these values outside the loop. This is what I've got, but it obviously doesn't work:

```
import psutil
import platform
from datetime import datetime
from tkinter import *
import threading
import os

def cpuinfo():

    while True:
        cpufreq = psutil.cpu_freq()
        maxfreq = f"Max Frequency: {cpufreq.max:.2f}Mhz"
        minfreq = f"Min Frequency: {cpufreq.min:.2f}Mhz"
        curfreq = f"Current Frequency: {cpufreq.current:.2f}Mhz"
       

        for i, percentage in enumerate(psutil.cpu_percent(percpu=True, interval=1)):
            usage = f"Core {i}: {percentage}%"

            

        total_cpu_usage = f"Total CPU Usage: {psutil.cpu_percent()}%"
        root.update()


x = threading.Thread(target=cpuinfo)
x.start()





root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x400")
cores = os.cpu_count()

for i in range(cores):

    label = Label(root, text=usage)
    label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: All of the variables you are setting inside `cpuinfo()` are local variables; they simply cannot be accessed from elsewhere in your program.  You can make them global - but this is an unnecessarily complicated approach: you're going to have to have code running periodically in the main thread to update your display, using Tkinter's `.after()` method - and that code could retrieve the CPU data itself, no threading needed.  You'd only actually need threading if the data retrieval was slow enough that doing it in the main thread made the GUI non-responsive.

Comment: Personally, I'd do this by making an _object_ that has those variables as members, and keeping a reference to the object outside the thread.

Comment: That said, creating a busy loop is generally a bad idea. This code is going to make your CPU waste a _lot_ of time updating statistics about itself for no good reason.

Comment: (one can stop it from _being_ a busy loop by adding a `time.sleep` call inside the thread, so it yields the CPU between updates)

Answer (score 1):

I re-wrote you script.

- Put `for` looping inside `while/else` block.
- Add two `Label` widgets.

Snippet:

```
import psutil
import platform
from datetime import datetime
from tkinter import *
import threading
import os

 

def cpuinfo():
    while True:
        cpufreq = psutil.cpu_freq()
        maxfreq = f"Max Frequency: {cpufreq.max:.2f}Mhz"
        minfreq = f"Min Frequency: {cpufreq.min:.2f}Mhz"
        curfreq = f"Current Frequency: {cpufreq.current:.2f}Mhz"
       

        for i, percentage in enumerate(psutil.cpu_percent(percpu=True, interval=1)):
            usage = f"Core {i}: {percentage}%"
            label.configure(text=usage)

            

        total_cpu_usage = f"Total CPU Usage: {psutil.cpu_percent()}%"
        label_1.configure(text=total_cpu_usage)
        root.update()

        cores = os.cpu_count()
        for i in range(cores):
            label_2.configure(text= i)


root = Tk()
root.title('CPU INFO')
root.geometry("200x100")
label = Label(root)
label.pack()

label_1 = Label(root)
label_1.pack()

label_2 = Label(root)
label_2.pack()
 
 

x = threading.Thread(target=cpuinfo)
x.start()

root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Very nice.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a `threading.Thread` object so you have state that's accessible from the parent process, and providing a callback to separate the generic "update statistics on a timer" job from the "update the UI with fresh statistics" job.

```
import psutil, time, threading, os

class CpuInfo(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, callback, delay=0.2):
        self.__cpufreq = psutil.cpu_freq()
        self.__callback = callback
        self.__delay = delay
    def run(self):
        while True:
            self.__cpufreq = psutil.cpu_freq()
            self.__callback(self)
            time.sleep(self.__delay)
    def maxfreq(self): return f"Max Frequency: {self.__cpufreq.max:.2f}Mhz"
    def minfreq(self): return f"Min Frequency: {self.__cpufreq.min:.2f}Mhz"
    def curfreq(self): return f"Current Frequency: {self.__cpufreq.current:.2f}Mhz"
    def total_cpu_usage(self): return f"Total CPU Usage: {psutil.cpu_percent()}%"
    def usage(self):
        return '\n'.join(
            f"Core {i}: {percentage}%"
            for i, percentage in enumerate(psutil.cpu_percent(percpu=True, interval=1))
        )

# put your tkinter logic here
def uiUpdate(cpuInfo):
  print("Updating the UI with new data:")
  print(cpuInfo.usage())

x = CpuInfo(uiUpdate)
x.start()
```